# Call java method based on Input in ExcelSheet

Tags: java, methods

Suppose i have some 10 test methods

method_1(),method_2().....method_10()
and i specify which test to run through Excel sheet as method_1 or method_2(method_testnumber) and based on the input read from excel sheet the method is run
Is there any way to achieve this behavior with out using "if" loop or "switch" case and just give a single line where the number alone varies.

eg: 
input="method_1";
Object.input();

Comment: use `reflection` to achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used Reflection to achieve the above behavior

```
java.lang.reflect.Method method;
try 
    {
      method = obj1.getClass().getMethod(methodname);
      method.invoke(obj1);
    } 
    catch (SecurityException e) 
    {}
    catch (NoSuchMethodException e)
    {}
```

where obj1=Object ,methodname=methodname input given through Excelsheet